# location clamav's .cvd files?

Tags: updates, clamav

I am trying to manually update ClamAV on a nas (non ubuntu based linux) for a friend, but i am not sure where to place the daily.cvd file.

I installed it automatically through the system but for one reason or another it doesn't want to update. Does anyone have any idea where the file daily.cvd is/should be located (on ubuntu system) so i might place it there manually?

Kind greats, Matthieu

Comment: Having used various systems with clamav, I've found the location varies on GNU/Linux (maybe even release with it changing over time, all I know is has varies on different boxes usually with different OS)

Answer (score 0):

I use ClamTK and have found the files in a hidden directory .clamtk so your files may well be in a directory`.clamav` in your `Home` directory. Igf using `Nautilus` you can see hidden directories by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>.
Reverse the process to hide them again.

There is then a subdirectory under that called `db` which contains the `.cvd` file `daily.cvd`

On the other hand [this reference](https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-install-and-use-clamav-antivirus-on-ubuntu-linux/) suggests that the file can be found in `/var/lib/clamav/daily.cvd`

You might also find [this reference](https://www.reviversoft.com/file-extensions/cvd) helpful.

Comment: thank you for your reply! at the moment i have no access to his pc, but i will in the end of the day and check this out after wich i will leave an update

Comment: unfortunately i haven't been able to find it. 
i gave it a test run on my own nas (same brand) but to no avail. i also installed fdfind and looked for files with the .cvd extention but didn't find. which  find odd as it has to be there on my system. so either i din't use it properly or something else is up.

Comment: i will try to contact the clamav developers

Comment: It's a hidden file.... View [ths reference](https://sourcedigit.com/26402-show-hidden-files-in-ubuntu-terminal/)